# Как выровнять прямые при помощи opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

Нужно сделать чётко прямые линии с фотографии.

К примеру у нас нарисован прямоугольник и он сфотографирован под углом.

Как выровнять линии этого прямоугольника?

Comment: Подушечность тоже нужно исправлять или линии уже прямые на фото?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если есть соответствие четырех пар точек, то построить матрицу перспективного преобразования с помощью [getPerspectiveTransform](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpperspective) и затем применить `warpPerspective`

[Пример на Py](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/)